# Specific question about the consequence of composing power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Please bear with my possible abuse of notation/terminology. Consider the power-series composition f(g(x)). If g's range lies within f's interval of convergence, and if series g has a constant term 0, then will the composed power series fg have the same interval of convergence as f?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No in general not, take $g(x)=x^3$ and let $f$ be a power series with convergence radius $8$, than $f(g(x))=f(x^3)$ has the radius of convergence $2$.

Another example is $g(x)=0$ than $f(g(x))=f(0)$ will have radius of convergence infinity.

If you say that the image is subset of the disc of convergence there are 2 cases: the first one is $f$ doesn't have convergence radius infty, than $g$ must be zero, cause $g$ is holomorphic and bounded and $g(0)=0$. hence $f(g(x))=f(g(0))=f(0)=0$ for all $x$ It is quite a boring case isn't it? The second case is that $f$ has convergence radius infty, than obviously $f\circ g$ has radius of convergence $\infty$.

Comment: In the first example, g's range isn't within f's radius of convergence, violating my first condition, right? In the second example, is your point that whatever f's radius of convergence, fg will have an infinite radius of convergence?

Comment: I guessed within meant not to be that the intersection is not empty. If you say that the image is subset of the radius of convergence there are 2 cases: the first one is $f$ doesn't have convergence radius infty, than $g$ must be zero, cause $g$ is holomorphic and bounded and $g(0)=0$. hence $f(g(x))=f(g(0))=f(0)=0$ for all $x$ It is quite a boring case isn't it? The second case is that $f$ has convergence radius infty, than obviously $f\circ g$ has radius of convergence $\infty$.

Comment: Oh I'm so silly!! I asked the wrong question, it should've been:   ".....then will the composed power series fg have the same interval of convergence as g?" (not "as f?"). Oh I wish I could delete this question. Hey, thank you for your answer.

Comment: still the answer will be the same, let $f=0$ and $g=\sum n! x^n$